# vertical search&compare column A and output newest date

Tags: vba, excel, search, compare

I am trying to make a vba code that searches trough a column for same value , and then return the newest date from column B
For example:

```
    column A     B            output C
    -------------------------------------
         102     12.01.2016   12.01.2016
         102     17.10.2015
         102     25.12.2015
         105     30.03.2015
         105     01.01.2016   01.01.2016
```

It should search to column A for diferent values. If it finds same values one after another then it will search for the newest date from the coresponding B column and outputed in column C
Please help me with a vba code.
Thank you

```
Sub Cauta()
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim k, t, i, j As Long
Dim stvalue As Integer
Dim lsvalue As Integer
Dim data As Date

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 2 To lRow
        stvalue = Cells(i, 2)
        t = 0
        For j = i To lRow
        If stvalue = Cells(j + 1, 2) Then
        t = t + 1
        Else: j = lRow
        data = Cells(j, 3)
        For k = i To i + t
        If Cells(k, 3) < Cells(k + 1, 3) Then data = Cells(k + 1, 3)
        Next k
        Cells(i + t, 6).Value = data
        End If
        Next j

        i = i + t
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: you didn't attach your code

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why do you need VBA?  A formula such as `=MAX(B2:B10)` will give the result you seek.

Comment: Sorry don't know how to attach a code now.

Comment: To include code: Click the edit button under your question.  Cody and paste your code into the edit window.

Comment: Sub Cauta()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim k, t, i, j As Long
Dim stvalue As Integer
Dim lsvalue As Integer
Dim data As Date
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 2 To lRow
        stvalue = Cells(i, 2)
        t = 0
        For j = i To lRow
        If stvalue = Cells(j + 1, 2) Then
        t = t + 1
        Else: j = lRow
        data = Cells(j, 3)
        For k = i To i + t
        If Cells(k, 3) < Cells(k + 1, 3) Then data = Cells(k + 1, 3)
        Next k
        Cells(i + t, 6).Value = data
        End If
        Next j
        i = i + t
    Next i
End sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with the changes I had made to allow me to understand your code.

Please fully indent your code; it is so much easier to read and so much easier to debug.

When you write `Dim k, t, i, j As Long`, only `j` is declared as `Long`.  `k`, `t` and `i` have no type so are declared as `Variant`.  `Variant` variables are larger and slower and are more likely to lead to errors.

Please do not use variable names like `k`, `t`, `i` and `j`.  Today you may remember what these names represent are but will you remember what they are when you return to this macro in a few months?  Even if you know what they are, no one else who looks at your code will know.  As I deduced what your code does, I have replaced such names with meaningful names.

The variable name `lRow` is slightly better but, in my view, not much better.  A lot of people prefix their variable names with a code representing their type. Given this, I interpreted `lRow` as `Long Row` since the variable is of type `Long`.  I do not prefix my names and prefer longer, more explicit names such as `RowLast`.

If you write `For A = B To C` ... `Next` you cannot change either `A` or `C` within the loop.  You do not change `C` but you do attempt to change `A`.  You can either rearrange your code so there is no need to change `A` or you can switch to a `Do While` Loop:

```
A = B
Do While A <= C
  :   :   :   :
Loop
```

I have switched to a `Do While` loop because it involves the least change to your code.

When you write `Dim stvalue As Integer`, `stvalue` is declared as a 16-bit integer.  16-bit integers require special processing on 32 and 64-bit computers and should be avoided.  Use type `Long`.

In your question, the layout of the table shows you are using columns “A”, “B” and “C” or 1, 2 and 3.  Your code uses columns 2, 3 and 6.  I do not know which is correct but it is better not to use column numbers in the code like this.  Suppose a new column 1 was added.  You would have to go through your code replacing every 2 by 3, 3 by 4 and 6 by 7.  You cannot just use global replace because there may be other 2s, 3s and 6s within the code.  Better to use constants to define column numbers.  They make the code easier to read and easier to maintain because 2, 3 and 6 only appear once.

Consider:

```
  For j = i To lRow
    If stvalue = Cells(j + 1, 2) Then
      t = t + 1
```

The last value for `j` will be `lRow + 1`.  Better to write:

```
  For j = i + 1 To lRow
    If stvalue = Cells(j, 2) Then
      t = l + 1
```

The `For j = i + 1 To lRow` loop finds how many rows have the same `Id` as row `i`. Within that loop you have `For k = i To i + t` to check the rows that are identical.  Two problems: (1) When the `k` loop finishes, you continue with the `j` loop. (2) Your question says you only want a value in the output column if there are multiple rows with the same Id.  I have made the nested `k` loop a separate loop with a test for multiple rows around it.

Your dates are formatted as “dd.mm.yyyy”.  That may be the default format for your country but it is not the default format for mine.  When you write a date to the output column, it will be displayed with your country’s default format.  To avoid problems, I have set the number format for the output column.

My final code is below.  I believe I have explained my changes adequately but come back with questions if necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Cauta()
  'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

  Const ColId As Long = 1      '\
  Const ColDate As Long = 2    '| Change these values as necessary
  Const ColOutput As Long = 3  '/


  Dim DateNewest As Date
  Dim IdFirst As Long
  Dim NumSameAsFirst As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long
  Dim RowNewest As Long
  Dim RowTemp As Long


    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    RowLast = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    RowCrnt = 2
    Do While RowCrnt <= RowLast
      IdFirst = Cells(RowCrnt, ColId)
      NumSameAsFirst = 0
      ' Count the number of rows with the same Id as RowCrnt
      For RowTemp = RowCrnt + 1 To RowLast
        If IdFirst = Cells(RowTemp, ColId) Then
          NumSameAsFirst = NumSameAsFirst + 1
        Else
          Exit For
        End If
      Next RowTemp
      If NumSameAsFirst > 0 Then
        DateNewest = Cells(RowCrnt, ColDate)
        RowNewest = RowCrnt
        For RowTemp = RowCrnt + 1 To RowCrnt + NumSameAsFirst
          If DateNewest < Cells(RowTemp, ColDate) Then
            DateNewest = Cells(RowTemp, ColDate)
            RowNewest = RowTemp
          End If
        Next RowTemp
        With Cells(RowNewest, ColOutput)
          .Value = DateNewest
          .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
        End With
      End If
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + NumSameAsFirst + 1
    Loop  ' While RowCrnt <= RowLast
End Sub
```

Comment: yes. Thanks very much it does the work and you really made a great tutorial for me to understand. it is one thing it does not do: if it is only one id it does not output the data for that id.

Comment: You made a great code here. I'm a noob... but i do want to learn more. It's a log way but still is a passion to figure it out

Comment: @toni1703. See point (2) in third paragraph from bottom of my answer. This seemed to be what you wanted. To record date against all Ids, delete `If NumSameAsFirst > 0 Then` and matching `End If`

Comment: @toni1703  We were all noobs once. I wish StackOverflow had existed when I was trying to learn VBA.  It would be helpful if you accepted the answer by clicking the big tick near the top.